# why android compiler generate different MethodRef for same code

Tags: android, javac, android-r8, android-d8, devirtualization

i happened to encounter some wired compiled bytecode which i believe both sharing the same source code like below

```java
class SomeWebView extends WebView {
   SomeWebView() {
      this.getSettings();      
   }
}
```

version 1 (above code write in app a) emits code like:

```
invoke-virtual **WebView**->getSettings() WebSettings, p0
```

version 2 (with same code copied to app b) emits code like:

```
invoke-virtual **SomeWebView**->getSettings() WebSettings, p0
```

although this changes nothing in correctness(?), but i want to know which step introduced this change and its official optimization name (like devirtualization? but i'm sure it's not)

notice SomeWebView DOES NOT override getSettings

Comment: Most likely, compileSdk was changed, or the version of the library from dependencies, from which WebView is imported.

Comment: Can you give more context here? If this an R8 compilation there are optimizations to reduce the number of method refs to make the code smaller.